# Project a name-value list into an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I want to be able to save an arbitrary flat object into the name-value list.

```
public class NameValueListEntity
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(NameValueListContentEntity.Entity))]
    public ICollection<NameValueListContentEntity> Content { get; set; }
}

public class NameValueListContent
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("entity_fk")]
    public NameValueListEntity Entity { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectToSave
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

I could use reflection to manually assemble/parse the list, but it will create a lot of overhead. Lots of `NameValueListContent` objects will be needlessly created both during the saving and the reading. Could it somehow be omitted? Especially during the reading, which is very performance-sensitive in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a AppDbContext class that holds your NameValueListContent class objects named as NVListContents. You can read and write the name-value list of objects by doing the following:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<NameValueListContent> NVListContents { get; set; }
    public AppDbContext()
        : base()
    { }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private AppDbContext context { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(AppDbContext _context)
    {
        context = _context;
    }

    public List<ObjectToSave> ReadObjects()
    {
        return context.NVListContents
            .Select(nvlc => new ObjectToSave { Prop1 = nvlc.Name, Prop2 = nvlc.Value 
                                             }).ToList();
    }
    
    public bool WriteObjects(int id, string name, string value)
    {
        var query = context.NVListContents
            .FirstOrDefault(nvlc => nvlc.Id == id);

        if(query != null)
        {
            query.Name = name;
            query.Value = value;

            context.Update(query);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, this answers to your question.